# Is it good practice to add extra methods in entity classes in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have node Entity. In database, I have id and title only and want to generate URL, my questions are

1. is it good practice to add extra methods to entity ?
2. is it ok to write doctrine query in entity ?

   ```
   $parent = $this->em->getRepository('MyDemoBundle:Nodes')->findOneBy(array("parentId" => $this->getParentId()));
   ```
3. is it ok to use `$this->getRequest()->getHost()` in entity which makes entity symfony dependent ?
4. Is it better to write getURL method in NodeRepository class ?
5. What should go in entity and what in repository class?

   ```
   class Node 
   {
       private $id;
       private $title;

      public function getId() 
      {
         return $this->id;
      }

      public function setId($id) 
      {
         $this->id = $id;
      }

      public function getTitle() 
      {
         return $this->title;
      }

     public function setTitle($title) 
     {
         $this->title = $title;
     }

     public function getURL ()
     {
           if ($this->getType() == "document") {
               $url = "http://".$this->getRequest()->getHost()."/research/" . preg_replace("/[-\s]+/", "-", strtolower(preg_replace("/[^-a-z0-9\s]+/i", "", trim($this->getTitle())))) . "-" . $this->getId() . "/";
           } elseif($this->getType() == "comment") {
               $parent = $this->em->getRepository('MyDemoBundle:Nodes')->findOneBy(array("parentId" => $this->getParentId()));
               if($this->getParentType() == "document"){
                   $url = "http://".$this->getRequest()->getHost()."/research/" . preg_replace("/[-\s]+/", "-", strtolower(preg_replace("/[^-a-z0-9\s]+/i", "", trim($parent->getTitle())))) . "-" . $this->getId();
               } else {
                   $url = "http://".$this->getRequest()->getHost()."/content/" . preg_replace("/[-\s]+/", "-", strtolower(preg_replace("/[^-a-z0-9\s]+/i", "", trim($parent->getTitle())))) . "-" . $this->getParentId() ;
               }
           } else {
               $url = "http://".$this->getRequest()->getHost()."/content/" . preg_replace("/[-\s]+/", "-", strtolower(preg_replace("/[^-a-z0-9\s]+/i", "", trim($this->getTitle())))) . "-" . $this->getId() . "/";
           }
       return $url;
      }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is bad. And besides this, you have no access to the request or the entity manager within the entity. A entity is a POPO (Plain old PHP object), i.e. a dummy only representing data.

If you want to get the parent with a getter, then should you notate a field with the right annotations/mappings (OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany). Read a little bit about in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations). With them you don't need to write any queries. Other queries go into the repository class.

And you should read a little bit about, [how urls are generated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls) in symfony. You don't need to refer to the host. a URL is mostly generated in the controller or the template you needs them to output.

btw. if you want slugged titles for urls you should take a look at the [sluggable behavior](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) of the doctrine extensions (installable with [DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle))

**All in all, you should read the [entire book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) to learn the basics!**

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to read about [How to create custom repository classses](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)
This is the right way to add "custom methods" tp entity classes in symfony

Here is the introduction of the article:

> In the previous sections, you began constructing and using more
>   complex queries from inside a controller. In order to isolate, reuse
>   and test these queries, it's a good practice to create a custom
>   repository class for your entity. Methods containing your query logic
>   can then be stored in this class.
>
> To do this, add the repository class name to your entity's mapping
>   definition: